# View that link to content in other languages

Tags: views, uri, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site where some content types are translated, and others will remain English only. I'd like to have lists of English content on other language sites. I've created a view that will list content from types that can not be translated, but the path variable is putting forward a translated link (e.g. **/fr/node/123**) even though it doesn't exist.

How do I get the link to the English version? If i have the node title "Link this field to the original piece of content " it links to the URL i am expecting, but I can't use that in rewriting...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `NID` field before the *Title* in *Fields* and make it *Exclude From Display*, I mean this

[image]

Then click on *Title* and in *Show Rewrite results*, check the *Output this field as a link* and use the following configuration

[image]

Now the *Title*s are linked to `/en/node/[nid]`

Comment: thanks, but that actually links them to /fr/en/node/[nid] ...

Comment: Try `use absolute path` in this way your problem will be solved